Vite application produces different localhost url on different systems
I'm QA and building pipeline script to run some UI tests against a web application. App is made with react & vite. My task is to write script which launches the app & tests. I got commands from developers to run the app locally and on windows it works perfectly. Example output is as follows:
➜  Local:   http://localhost:4173/
and then I can access application on given port. When I exported whole branch & configuration on azure pipeline, to agent based on linux and runnigg very same command, I got a following output then:
 ➜  Local:  http://localhost:4173/%22/%22
I read that %22 is encoded double quotas " but I don't know if I can do anything about it.
I tried to reach out with my tests to following urls:
http://localhost:4173/%22/%22
http://localhost:4173/
http://localhost:4173
and for first two URLS I got blank screen with text "Cannot GET / ". And for third one completely bank screen. Is there anything as QA i can do there? Or it can be matter that app is not supported to be built on linux?
